# Different ways of indexing dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say, I have a dataframe `df` in R as follows,

```
     id     inflam
1   1 0.03093764
2   2 0.50115406
3   3 0.82153770
4   4 0.01985961
5   5 0.04994588
6   6 0.91714810
7   7 0.83438400
8   8 0.80832225
9   9 0.12360681
10 10 0.08490079
```

I can access the entirety of the `inflam` column by indexing as `df[,2]` or `df[2]`. However, `typeof(df[,2])` returns `double`, whereas `typeof(df[2])` returns `list`. The comma seems to be the differentiator, but why is this the case? What is going on under the hood?

Comment: See e.g. https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/misc/brackets.html. To get the equivalent of `df[, 2]` one needs to use `df[[2]]`. Part of the confusion comes from the fact that data.frame allow both matrix-like subsetting (`m[r, c]`) and list subsetting (`l[e]` and `l[[e]]`).

Comment: Possible (probable) duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/324364